# Site looks vastly different on different machines when using same browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web, cross-browser

My problem is this:  A site I'm working on has issues with IE8.  The machine that I'm using runs 10 and I've been using 8 & 9 from the developer mode.  Looks OK.  I then tested it using IETester, again, not as pretty as expected but looks fine.

Someone else tested on their work machine and it looks like complete and utter garbage, layout changed etc.

I asked them to check several times by several different methods (machine info.com, if IE statements, about IE and so on) and all the tests revealed they were using IE8.

By using IETester, the closest I've come to represent what they're seeing is by using IE6 & 7 but how is this possible?

Its a compnay machine so I can't see any reason why the settings would be altered, if indeed they can to that extent.

Is there an explanation for this?  I'm running out of options and at a bit of a loss.

If anyone is running IE8 and would like to check, the site is www.kingpetroleum.co.uk

Thanks.

Comment: IE8 mode in IE10 and **actual** IE8 do work/look different, annoying I know.

Comment: But it's a LOT different and in IETester it looks ok too

Comment: There's no realistic way that someone can help you with this. You've got to roll up you sleeves, install IE8 somewhere and get digging.

Comment: I'm hoping someone else might come along that  might've had the same experience.

Comment: Open IE 9 or 10, Press F12 and put documentmodes on IE7. You will see that its looks differnt.

Comment: Yep, I've had issues like that. Everyone of them has been a different problem (well not true but you see what I'm saying) I really don't think your going to find a *magic bullet*, good luck! :)

Comment: @S.Visser - wow.  now it looks the same...fking ugly.

Comment: @S.Visser - seeing as I'm now seeing the same issues but using the IE7 docs...does that mean I need ot code for IE7 instead of 8?

Comment: What is the Doctype that you are using? <!DOCTYPE html> ?

Comment: @sbml, It shoudl be visible in the post, last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people have IE8 ( or 9 and 10 ) but running on the document modes of IE7. The problem is that you use `:after` and `:before` in your CSS. IE7 does not support this.

*To see: Open Internet explore > press F12 > put documentmodes on IE7*

Try to search for a workaround for `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: Why would people do that?!!?? -.-

Comment: Dont know, had couple of clients that had that to. Maybe there is a shortcut that activates it, not sure.

Comment: Madness.  I've found a couple of posts for workarounds, jsut need ot find one that works, thank you again, I had no idea it was the cause.